# NTFS mount problem

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, mount

I was unable to mount two of the partitions mainly due to fast boot up feature of windows 8 , but by mistake without checking the mounted partitions, I removed windows via OS- unistaller .
Now  cannot mount my two partitions.. So what should be done to recover my partitions.

Comment: @EliahKagan I think this is not about recovering data. Fastboot marks the partitions as unclean so Ubuntu throws errors when you try to mount them. The usual response to this is to boot into Windows, disable fastboot, and make a proper shutdown or reboot. But if Windows is gone, then how does one mark the FS as clean?

Comment: @muru I think you're right. I've removed my close vote. (I'll remove this comment soon too, but you may want to keep yours, at least until/unless the question is expanded by editing.)